# How do I call a python object from a parameter

Tags: python, class

Is it possible to use a parameter in a class as an identification of the object? For example:

```
class simpleclass:
     def __init__(self, name):
          self.name = name

myobject = simpleclass("Jerry")
myobject2 = simpleclass("Jimmy")
```

how do I call all objects that have the name of "Jerry"?
Is it even possible? Thanks!

Comment: `list_of_objs = [myobject, myobject2]` `jerrys = [obj for obj in list_of_objs if obj.name == "Jerry"]`

Comment: your init statement is wrong. it should be `__init__`

Comment: If you had a set `simples` of simpleclass instances, then `Jerrys = {simple.'Jerry' for simple in simples}.  However, simpleclass instances are not callable.

Comment: also, use `self` as the first arg to member methods

Comment: Fixed the mistakes, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the `name` attribute is `'Jerry'` for each object that you want to check:

```
objects = [myobject, myobject2, ...]
[obj for obj in objects if obj.name == 'Jerry']
```

Comment: This seems to be close, I can tweak it to give me the correct list I want by putting it in a separate for function. However, I can't get your snippet to yield anything in the list, it'd be nice if you can find the problem for other people trying to achieve this.

Comment: @HasithVattikuti I'm not sure why you can't get it to work. It works fine for me. And it should be no different than a for-loop with the same structure.

Comment: ‍♂️ I was looking for an ID (integer) in my code but tried to search for a string. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may want to use a dictionary to map an object's identifier to a list of all objects with the same identifier. Below is an example.

```
from collections import defaultdict

simpleclass_list_by_name = defaultdict(list)
simpleclass_list_by_name['Jerry'].append(simpleclass('Jerry'))
simpleclass_list_by_name['Jerry'].append(simpleclass('Jerry'))

for name in simpleclass_list_by_name:
    simpleclass_list = simpleclass_by_name[name]
    for sc in simpleclass_list:
        # do something
```